# how to activate google cloud trial account with my debit card because it says We weren’t able to establish your payments profile how to fix this?

Tags: console

When I pay the 1 rs amount from account by entering my debit card details google responds as:

```markdown
Contact us to get started

We weren’t able to establish your payments profile. To finish setting up your 
free trial, get help from our Support team.
```

How to fix that ?